# heroku pg:psql does nothing

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to get create my database, but I can't get heroku pg:psql and nothing happens. When I try using heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL nothing  happens either. Not sure why. 
[My command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np1jQ.png)

Comment: Recently just answered for similar issue that is applicable on your case as well – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465746/heroku-pgpsql-not-working/40018443#40018443

Comment: I've already seen that. If you look at my image, it isn't giving me those errors

Comment: Right, misread the error message. This is Ruby error not exactly Heroku. But since Heroku Toolbelt is built on top of Ruby then it uses it. Regard of that Ruby issue here seems to have same error experience answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146567/how-to-solve-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle-rails-4-1-8